# How can I force the user login before go to any where in my application?

Tags: asp.net, session, redirect, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on the asp.net mvc5 project, my problem is forcing the user login then they can go anything on my site. **I'm using Session to check user login or not (I'm not using Identity or Authorization)**.
**Here is my Login code:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(User user)
    {
        if (IsValid(user.username, user.password))
        {
            Session["username"] = user.username;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

I can check the user login or not with Session but I cannot deny the user access to the link, if I have to do this manually, I will need to add the block code below to any action in every controller I have.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["username"] != null)
        {
            //then user can go anywhere with any link
        }
        else
        {
            //user cannot go to here without login
        }
    }
```

There is any way I can force the user to redirect to the login page (if they are not login) when they click on any link or type the link in the browser? I was searching about config the route or using filter config but it seems not to solve my problem. I hope there has the general way to do this without adding the check-code manually to each controller/action.

Thanks for reading my problem, I will be very appropriated any comment to help me solve this.

Comment: Try to Redirect him to the start page if there is no session.

Comment: @WasteD I can check and redirect the user to the login page but I need to copy the detect login code to any controller or action that user can come. That will be the final way if I cannot solve this. I need to know if there are anyway more general than my specified code. Anyway, Thanks for replying me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to tackle on this globally is to override the `OnActionExecuting` method on the controller, that does the check and redirects to the homepage if no user is logged or allows the action if there is a user.

This can be done on a base controller so that it applies to all the website (by making all controllers inherit from this one).

```cs
public abstract class LoginRequiredController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Session["username"] != null)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            //Redirect to the main page, or login, or somewhere else, without running the requested action
            filterContext.Result = Redirect("/");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Controllers inheriting from this one will check on each request that there is a user, and redirected to the main page in case there isn't one, without needing to copy/paste this check for each method.

Of course, the login controller should not inherit from it or it would be impossible to login at all.